# NG-bootstrap close popover from container

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have a container component (called `file-container`) with an `ngbPopover` button. The content of the popover is another component. (It is used to select a file for upload).

```
<button type="button" 
        class="btn btn-secondary popover-btn" 
        placement="top"
        [ngbPopover]="popContent" 
        popoverTitle="Click to add files - will be a label" 
        container="body" 
        trigger="manual"
        #popover="ngbPopover"
        (click)="populateDropdownList()">
  Click to add files
</button>
<template #popContent>
  <app-file-uploader [maxFiles]="maxFiles"
                      [fileNames]="fileNames"
                      (onUpload)="uploadEboxAttachment($event)">
  </app-file-uploader>
</template>
```

The app-file-uploader emits an event when the `Upload` button is clicked.
The container component handles the actual file upload to the server.
I want the `file-container` TypeScript code to handle closing the popover too. So that after it recieves a reply from the server, it closes the popover.
How can I pass the popover to the `.ts` file so that I can call `.close()` on it?
EDIT- ts code:

```
createEboxAttachment(event):Observable<any>{
  return new Observable<any>(observer => {
    this.jsConnection.sobject("EBOX_Attachment__c").create({Name : event.selectedFile, Tender_Reply__c : this.tender.Reply.Id})
      .then(ret => observer.next(ret))
      .catch(error => observer.error(error));
  });
}

createAttachment(base64data, event, ret):Observable<any>{
  let name = event.selectedFile == this.$Label.EBOX_Other ? event.file.name : event.selectedFile;
  return new Observable<any>(observer => {
    this.jsConnection.sobject("Attachment").create({
        ParentId : ret.id,
        Name : name,
        Body : base64data.substring(base64data.lastIndexOf('base64,')+7),
        ContentType : event.file.type
      })
      .then(ret => observer.next(ret))
      .catch(error => observer.error(error));
  });
}

sendAttachToSF(base64data, event){
  this.createEboxAttachment(event).subscribe(
    ret => {
      this.createAttachment(base64data, event, ret).subscribe(att => {
        this.fileUploaded(att, event);
      });
    },
    error => this.toastr.error(error)
  );
}

uploadEboxAttachment(event){
  if (!this.jsConnection){
    this.jsConnection = window["jsConnection"];
  }
  let reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = (e) => (this.sendAttachToSF(reader.result, event));
  reader.readAsDataURL(event.file);
}

fileUploaded(result, event){
  // this.popover.close(); would like to close popover here.
  this.onFileUploaded.emit(att); //emit event to parent component. works
}
```

Comment: After upload you won't get the reply from your backend.

Comment: Hi have you tried with private @ViewChild("#popContent") popOver; and then something like on the MYSERVICECALLTOBACKEND.then((resp)=> {   this.popOver.close() }  )

Comment: @RomanC - I am getting the reply from the backend. I would like to call the `close()` after I receive confirmation from my Observable (I know that that part works becuase I am doing other things then).

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi - We tried something like that and it didn't work.

Comment: mmm really strange can you post your ts code?

Comment: @AvailableName How would you like to do it. Getting observable is you only need to subscribe to the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION that I stumbled upon (thought of in the shower at 2 am).
Since I'm calling a function when the button is clicked and the popover is opened (to populate a dynamic dropdown menu), then I just call that function with the ngbPopover as a parameter.
`(click)="populateDropdownList(popover)"`
So, it may be ugly, but now I have the popover inside my TS code, and I can close the popver whenver I want.

Comment: works like a charm, never underestimate the 2am shower times haha +1

Answer (score 2):

Demo is available here:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gjunnt?file=app/popover-basic.ts

Output can be seen in below link:
 https://angular-gjunnt.stackblitz.io

You can follow the below code:

1. html template file

   ```
   <ng-template #popContent>
   <ngb-alert *ngIf="maskEditorAppliedMessage" type="success" (close)="closePopover()">{{ maskEditorAppliedMessage }}</ngb-alert>
   </ng-template>
   <div [ngbPopover]="popContent" #popOver="ngbPopover" triggers="manual" placement="bottom"></div>


   <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mr-2" (click)="openPopover()">
     Apply
   </button>
   ```
2. You can have the below code in your ts file.

   ```
   import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
   import { NgbPopover } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

   @Component({
     selector: 'ngbd-popover-basic',
     templateUrl: './popover-basic.html'
   })
   export class NgbdPopoverBasic {
     maskEditorAppliedMessage: string;
     @ViewChild('popOver') public popover: NgbPopover;

     public closePopover(): void {
       this.maskEditorAppliedMessage = null;
       if (this.popover.isOpen()) this.popover.close();
     }

     public openPopover(): void {
       console.log('open' + this.popover.isOpen());
       this.maskEditorAppliedMessage = "Successfully Applied";
       if (!this.popover.isOpen()) this.popover.open();
     }
   }
   ```